# How to fix the bug in sending mail via Java

Tags: java

problem in sending mail via java programe

hi, I want to send mail from gmail via java programe. When i am trying the various code include javatpoint it shows an Exception. the exception is -

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbvIk
534-5.7.14 cT546iWrmHVjdqIAu4bu64fGl37lt-4vX0RaunTx73hKE4HpZRQY7JSqatKptl8zIIy0XC
534-5.7.14 6mOUSMf5eDqgUnxViCrlbAb0pgjgVVJ4is21WFaCiKQgRMsNZrJ1zeZvMgOp4bHj1oAkRg
534-5.7.14 FIX765BcLczE1J3OnvGtMfKRU4qhJ9gCNU6pXNoiy9QJBQwraCqOhljfO8sI31DzDNSu9y
534-5.7.14 MYa-oA31ONPvip2QGCGj8Bxzzhbo> Please log in via your web browser and
534-5.7.14 then try again.
534-5.7.14  Learn more at
534 5.7.14  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 y5sm11829169pbt.77 - gsmtp
```

Any ideas what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably should go to [Google account settings](https://myaccount.google.com/security) and disable 2-step verification for password and under "Account permission" enable "Access for less secure apps" as well